# Convert disk to RAID 1? Rescue mode

Tags: disk, raid

How can I convert my current setup to a RAID 1 setup

```
 root@rescue:~# fdisk -l /dev/sda /dev/sdb

Disk /dev/sda: 447.1 GiB, 480103981056 bytes, 937703088 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x03c70bcf

Device     Boot   Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *       2048   1126399   1124352   549M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2       1126400 937701039 936574640 446.6G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Disk /dev/sdb: 447.1 GiB, 480103981056 bytes, 937703088 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 455FA666-C539-4642-B924-B4D8622682AA
```

cat /proc/mdstat

```
Personalities : [linear] [raid0] [raid1] [raid10] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [multipath] [faulty]
unused devices: <none>
```

df -h

```
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                            16G     0   16G   0% /dev
178.33.xxx.49:/home/pub/rescue.v8  1.8T  369G  1.3T  23% /nfs
tmpfs                               16G  1.4M   16G   1% /rw
aufs                                16G  1.4M   16G   1% /
178.33.xxx.49:/home/pub/pro-power  1.8T  369G  1.3T  23% /power
178.33.xxx.49:/home/pub/commonnfs  1.8T  369G  1.3T  23% /common
tmpfs                               32G     0   32G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                               16G  9.7M   16G   1% /run
tmpfs                              5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                               16G     0   16G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs                               16G  8.0K   16G   1% /tmp
```

lsblk

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sdb      8:16   0 447.1G  0 disk
sda      8:0    0 447.1G  0 disk
├─sda2   8:2    0 446.6G  0 part
└─sda1   8:1    0   549M  0 part
```

I would like to convert the system to RAID 1 on `/dev/sda` & `/dev/sdb`

Comment: Added them above

Comment: What's in the `lsblk`? I want to determine if you use LVM or not.

Comment: In your original question, the large `fdisk` output contained partition table entries for `/dev/sdb`. In this edited version it does not. If they were omitted from the revised outuput by mistake please add them back. Can you also please add `fdisk -l /dev/md[0-9]*` to your list of disks/partitions too - it's my mistake I forgot to include this in my original request. Thanks

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov Added above

Comment: @roaima It was changed I tried to clear the disk.

Comment: OK it would be worth clarifying, I think, where your important data resides that much not under any circumstances be lost :-) If I were you I'd also be looking to borrow or acquire a disk to take a full and complete backup of my data "just in case". Disk to RAID is not a _guaranteed safe_ operation

Comment: @roaima No the data can be lost it's a new setup feel free to test away

Comment: Then why don't you just reinstall it from scratch? It is faster and easier than "converting", because installer will do everything for you. // Also, do you plan to use UEFI boot, or "legacy"?

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov I did not install the system it was imported wget -O- 'https://website.com/Windows2019.gz' | gunzip | dd of=/dev/sda

Comment: Why are you asking about Windows on "Unix & Linux Stack Exchange"? That's off topic here. If you are going to remove it and install Linux, go ahead and boot an installer. If you want to convert Windows installation to use RAID, please ask somewhere else.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because you can't use Linux-based softRAID in a Windows image installation